# 5v relay module not working with dc adapter

Tags: arduino, diodes, relay, charger

I have a setup with a relay that disconnects mains voltage for a project.the problem i have is that the relay works fine when i connect it to the arduino and  power it from a laptop but i changed the source to a mobile charger with sufficient current rating it just keep turning on and off .i think that after turning on it keeps shorting as the arduino resets too i have also tried it directly by removing arduino and just powering it through the charger same thing happens. i have changed the charger once too . one thing to be noted is that i  tried another cell phone charger with output:5v and current :1A it worked with it . [image]

(x)

** EDIT:** turns out it was my own mistake ,the input wiring for powering the charger were mixed with the relay . fixed now thank you all for the help !

Comment: I don't understand - your text says to "replace the Arduino with the cell charger". Are you using the charger to run the Arduino or not?  Please edit your post to make this more clear. A schematic would be helpful too.

Comment: @mike65535 read now.

Answer (score 1):

*but i changed the source to a mobile charger*

Aha! Many mobile chargers (power banks) **switch off** when the load only draws a small current. This is likely the reason why the power is switched off. The Arduino + relay simply doesn't draw enough current to keep the power bank switched on.

The power bank "thinks" there's nothing connected so it switches off.

Your alternative is to use a power bank that is doesn't switch off at a low current.

You could also increase the load (for example by connecting a 27 ohm, 1 Watt resistor between 5V and GND) to keep the power bank awake but that will very likely drain your power bank much more quickly.

Comment: i have check with a voltmeter it shows 5v or does it only switches off the current supply?

Comment: The current and voltage are related so you cannot just "switch off the current supply" while the 5 V remains present. It matters a lot **how** you measured that 5 V. It can be that the powerbank only **shortly** removes the 5V, then detects that some load is there and switches on again. That gives a short interruption of the 5 V supply, enough to reset the Arduino.

Comment: yea i think thaat is the case it keeps turning on and off only when i connect the relay other wise it powers the arduino and hc06 just fine

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually measure the current out of the cell charger under load, don't count on the printed current rating.  I have seen these types of chargers/ext power supplies go bad and unable to supply required load current but voltage readings are still good.
Measure your load current draw when powered from your laptop.  In the USB 1.0 and 2.0 specs, a standard downstream port is capable of delivering up to 500mA (0.5A); with USB 3.0, it moves up to 900mA (0.9A).  Do the same using the mobile charger.  If it power cycle before reaching the current measured when powered from your laptop, replace the mobile charger.  It would help if you have a meter that holds min/max values.

Comment: i only have a analog meter but i will try to measure the current .

Comment: its about 45 mA with aruido + hc06 + relay and with charger and relay its about 60 mA

Comment: Why is there a 10mA difference when you remove the Arduino?  You should be drawing more current with the relay "on" when controlled by the Arduino.  You don't suppose you have the polarity reversed on your first charger, do you?

Comment: nah i am using a data cable so the polarity couldnt have been reversed

Comment: Remove the relay from the circuit and only power the Arduino with the mobile charger.  If there is no power cycle, then the problem is the relay.  If there is power cycling, then the problem is the mobile charger.  Your project is pretty straight forward.  If other power sources works except the mobile charger, guess where the issue lies.  Get a nice digital multimeter.  You don't have to get a Fluke since there are many digital multimeters out there that will do the job.

Comment: without the relay evrything works fine even with the relay until its triggered it works fine as soon as it gets triggered it short circuit the whole system which disbales the bluetooth and resets the arduino. i hvae tried 3 different chargers with different ratings same probelm.

Comment: "one thing to be noted is that i tried another cell phone charger with output:5v and current :1A it worked with it ."  Check the current draw on your relay circuit when triggered using the 5V, 1A charger you used before that worked.